# Is there a real need in an Anti-XSS in web forms today

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, webforms, .net-4.5

Well, my company have a webs site which contains 5 pages of web forms and 2 mvc,

and we were thinking to put the (Microsoft AntiXSS / Web protection) which should protect agiest XSS, but then iv'e read that its a part of the .net 4.5, which means i don't need to put anything to protect myself agiesnt XSS?

In out code behind we check every text box that comes to the server(If its need to be int, then its check to int, if guid, checked to guid). is there any real need to another thing to protect?

Thanks so much.!

Comment: If you are correctly encoding for every output context you use (i.e. output to HTML, JavaScript, JSON, etc), then you do not necessarily need Microsoft AntiXSS. Check out the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to make sure your code is doing this properly.

Answer (score 1):

From What's New 4.5 these routines are included, but still need to be used.
[What's New in ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411060052/http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new)

**AntiXSS Library**

Due to the popularity of the Microsoft AntiXSS Library, ASP.NET 4.5 now incorporates core encoding routines from version 4.0 of that library.

The encoding routines are implemented by the AntiXssEncoder type in the new System.Web.Security.AntiXss namespace. You can use the AntiXssEncoder type directly by calling any of the static encoding methods that are implemented in the type. However, the easiest approach for using the new anti-XSS routines is to configure an ASP.NET application to use the AntiXssEncoder class by default. To do this, add the following attribute to the Web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime
  encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web,
    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

When the encoderType attribute is set to use the AntiXssEncoder type, all output encoding in ASP.NET automatically uses the new encoding routines.

These are the portions of the external AntiXSS library that have been incorporated into ASP.NET 4.5:

- *HtmlEncode, HtmlFormUrlEncode, and HtmlAttributeEncode*
- *XmlAttributeEncode and XmlEncode*
- *UrlEncode and UrlPathEncode (new)*
- *CssEncode*